# codes about smart pointer failed

Tags: c++, c++11

I just try codes about smart pointers in C++ Primer, and I can't find any problems in it. It is very similar to the codes in the book.

#### Code:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <memory> 

std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> *my_malloc() { 
    return std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(); 
}
```

#### Compiler Errors:

```
12_7.cc:6:12: error: no viable conversion from
  'typename enable_if<!is_array<vector<int, allocator<int> > >::value, shared_ptr<vector<int, allocator<int> > > >::type'
  (aka 'std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >')
 to 
  'std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> > *' 

return std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(); 
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `my_malloc` function declares that it returns the pointer to shared pointer (which is weird and probably wrong), and then you return shared pointer (just as you should). Try

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> my_malloc() { 
  return std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> *` means a *pointer to* a shared pointer to a vector of integers.  You're trying to return a `shared_ptr` from a function that's supposed to return a `shared_ptr*`.

You probably intended for your function to return an actual `shared_ptr`, not a (non-shared) pointer to one, so just remove the `*`.